# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: main [class [Ljava.lang.String;]

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I don't know what is wrong with the code below when I carefully follow the module given to me. pls, teach me why I'm getting that error. I'm totally a newbie on java while my professor not replying to me.

```js
  public class Member{
  String name;
  int age;
  String number;
  String address;
  int salary;

  public void printSalary(){
    System.out.println(salary);
  }

}

class Employee extends Member{
  String specialization;
}

class Manager extends Member{
  String department;
}

class Ans{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.name = "Lado";
    e.age = 21;
    e.number = "0919467670";
    e.address = "Tunasan";
    e.salary = 10000;
    e.specialization = "Computer Coding";

    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.name = "Lala";
    m.age = 23;
    m.number = "09216t767";
    m.address = "Tunasan";
    m.salary = 0;
    m.department = "CITS Office";
  }
```

Comment: If you're trying to run this directly using the "single-source" feature using `java Member.java`, where you don't need to compile first, then the class with `main` must be **first**, and *it* should be the `public` class. --- Otherwise, compile with `javac Member.java` and run with `java Ans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Remove "public"
 class Member{
  String name;
  int age;
  String number;
  String address;
  int salary;

  public void printSalary(){
    System.out.println(salary);
  }

}

class Employee extends Member{
  String specialization;
}

class Manager extends Member{
  String department;
}

// Add "public", don't forget that the name of this java file must be "Ans.java"
public class Ans{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.name = "Lado";
    e.age = 21;
    e.number = "0919467670";
    e.address = "Tunasan";
    e.salary = 10000;
    e.specialization = "Computer Coding";

    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.name = "Lala";
    m.age = 23;
    m.number = "09216t767";
    m.address = "Tunasan";
    m.salary = 0;
    m.department = "CITS Office";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man, i thought the name would be it main class

Comment: The class with method `main()` does not have to be `public`. It can even be a `private static` nested class. So OP could have left the source file as-is and simply done what I said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497192/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-main-class-ljava-lang-string?noredirect=1#comment119302837_67497192): "compile with `javac Member.java` and run with `java Ans`."

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `main` method in a public class or it won't be picked up. Since you can only have one public class per file (compilation unit), you have to make `Member` not public or move it to another file:

```
class Member{
    String name;
    int age;
    String number;
    String address;
    int salary;

    public void printSalary(){
        System.out.println(salary);
    }

}

class Employee extends Member{
    String specialization;
}

class Manager extends Member{
    String department;
}

public class Ans{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.name = "Lado";
        e.age = 21;
        e.number = "0919467670";
        e.address = "Tunasan";
        e.salary = 10000;
        e.specialization = "Computer Coding";

        Manager m = new Manager();
        m.name = "Lala";
        m.age = 23;
        m.number = "09216t767";
        m.address = "Tunasan";
        m.salary = 0;
        m.department = "CITS Office";
   }
```

}

Also the name of the .java source file always has to match the name of the public class, so this has to be in `Ans.java`.

Comment: The class with method `main()` does not have to be `public`. It can even be a `private static` nested class.